# Deprecate certain methods/types

Tags: .net, compiler-construction, static-analysis

To prevent using some members (or types) is there a way to mark them as obsolete (and sometimes in the future remove them completely).

But is there a way to deprecate members (or types) of the compiled third-party assemblies? Or, at least, to make sure (or to issue a warning) when they are used?

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered crafting a [custom Code Analysis/FxCop rule](http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/)?

Answer (score 2):

As you can tell from the answers so far, there isn't a great, built-in way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [NDepend](http://www.ndepend.com/) for this as well

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could subclass the entire library (or at least the parts you use) and then deprecate them any way you like.

Comment: The types could be sealed, could be interfaces, etc. Even for virtual methods, it wouldn't affect the caller unless they were changed to refer to your sub class, etc. In short, I'm not sure this is viable.

Comment: The other side of it is taht it's not your software; it may have lots of version dependencies that you don't anticipate; and if you could impose arbitrary deprecation attributes without your own signature on them, then inevitably you would end up eventually conflicting something from the publisher.